# First login attempt works if it's correct, but if it's incorrect then other correct attempts don't work

Tags: c++, c++builder, ado, tadoquery

```
void __fastcall TFormLogin::btnLoginClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    UnicodeString query = "select * from admin where korisnickoIme = '" + editKorisnicko->Text +
                     "' AND lozinka = '" + editLozinka->Text + "'";
    AnsiString ansiQuery = query;

    ADOQuery1->ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=KnjiznicaManagement;Data Source=KUKICRO\\SQLEXPRESS;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=KUKICRO;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False";
    ADOQuery1->SQL->Add(ansiQuery);

    ADOQuery1->Prepared = true;

    try
    {
        ADOQuery1->Active = true;
    }
    catch (EADOError& e)
    {
        MessageDlg("Error spajanja", mtError,
                      TMsgDlgButtons() << mbOK, 0);
        return;
    }

    TDataSource* Src = new TDataSource(this);
    Src->DataSet = ADOQuery1;
    Src->Enabled = true;

    if(Src->DataSet->RecordCount < 1){
        labelPrijava->Visible = true;
        ADOQuery1->Prepared = false;

        Src->Enabled = false;

        try{
            ADOQuery1->Active = false;
        }
        catch (EADOError& e){
            MessageDlg("Error odspajanja", mtError,
                  TMsgDlgButtons() << mbOK, 0);
        }
        return;
    }

    FormMain->labelUlogiran->Caption = Src->DataSet->FieldByName("korisnickoIme")->AsString;
    FormLogin->Close();
}
```

Code from above is my `OnClick` button event code. It should simulate login from a database table "admin" that contains "korisnickoIme" in the username field and "lozinka" in the password field. When I type in the correct username and password, the first attempt works, but if I type in the wrong username and password and then the correct one, it doesn't work. When I go through with the debugger, the last `if` is true but it shouldn't be.

Comment: No way we can see through all the hidden code. I.e. I have no idea why that line is expecting to throw an error, it shouldn’t in my brain.

Comment: This is just a guess, but you seem to be adding queries to your `ADOQuery1->SQL` object without clearing them first, so it is possibly always just running the first query again whenever you click the button.

Comment: @TheDark you were right, thanks for the solution.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then, in case someone with a similar problem finds this question in the future.

Comment: @Lovro On a side note, why are you using `AnsiString` at all? `SQL->Add()` takes a `UnicodeString`, so you are converting `UnicodeString` to `AnsiString` (which is a potentially lossy conversion) just to convert back to `UnicodeString`. Also, your code is susceptible to an SQL Injection attack, you should use a [parameterized query](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Parameters_in_Queries) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
ADOQuery1->SQL->Add(ansiQuery);
```

adds the `ansiQuery` to the end of the SQL collection for `ADOQuery`. When you  click the button a second time, the new query is added to the end, but the original incorrect query is still at the start of the collection, so it is run first.

Solution: Clear out the collection on each button click. Add the following before the `Add` line:

```
ADOQuery1->SQL->Clear()
```

Comment: Or, use `ADOQuery1->SQL->Text = query;` instead.